# Bulk Disable PowerShell Script Not Executing

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am kinda new to powershell and started a role in support. Working on a powershell script that will do the following things:

1. Disable a user account
2. Remove all AD Groups except for Domain Users
3. Edit the description
4. Move AD object to a disabled users OU

I think I can probalby change the "$TargetOU = OUPath" because the disabled users OU is never really going to change...if that's the issue then i'll feel like a dumby lol.

I am trying and failing to complete this! I don't know what is going wrong. Powershell isn't faulting out or anything it is just not executing?

Thank you for any help!

My code is here:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$TargetOU = "OU=DisabledUsers"
Import-Csv "C:temp\DisableTest.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $samAccountName = $_."samAccountName" 
    Get-AdPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $samAccountName {Where-Object -Property Name -Ne -Value     'Domain Users' | Remove-AdGroupMember -Members $samAccountName}
    Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName | Disable-ADAccount
    Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName -Description "Disabled Per Request XXXX"
    Move-ADObject -Identity $UserDN -TargetPath $TargetOU
}
```

Need it to do four things:

1. Disable a user account
2. Remove all AD Groups except for Domain Users
3. Edit the description
4. Move AD object to a disabled users OU

Comment: i see just as quickly you OU is not ok $moveToOU = "OU=Disabled Accounts,OU=User Accounts,OU=Logon Accounts and Groups,DC=companyname,DC=local"

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues:

```
$TargetOU = "OU=DisabledUsers"
```

This should be the full distinguished name, so something like `OU=DisabledUsers,DC=example,DC=com`

```
Get-AdPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $samAccountName {Where-Object -Property Name -Ne -Value     'Domain Users' | Remove-AdGroupMember -Members $samAccountName}
```

The sytax here is messed up. You want to pipe (`|`) the results from `Get-AdPrincipalGroupMembership` into `Where-Object`, but you have braces (`{`). The closing brace at the end of the line is thus unnecessary. The [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) cmdlet also lets you simplify the syntax to something more readable, like `Where Name -ne 'Domain Users'`.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $samAccountName -Description "Disabled Per Request XXXX"
```

This should be `Set-ADUser`, which is explains why this isn't changing anything.

```
Move-ADObject -Identity $UserDN -TargetPath $TargetOU
```

You haven't defined `$UserDN`, so it's not going to find the user. And as already mentioned , the target path should be the full distinguished name.

You're also looking up the account several times. Every time you pass just the username, it has to search for the account. As you have it, it would be searching for the account 5 times. You can avoid that (and speed things up) by calling `Get-ADUser` once and passing the result into each of the other commands.

And just for simplicity, you can omit `-Identity` since the first parameter is assumed to be the identity.

Putting everything together, it would look something like this:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$TargetOU = "OU=DisabledUsers,DC=example,DC=com" #Change this to the real value
Import-Csv "C:temp\DisableTest.csv" | ForEach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser $_."samAccountName"
    Get-AdPrincipalGroupMembership $user | Where Name -ne 'Domain Users' | Remove-AdGroupMember -Members $user
    Disable-ADAccount $user
    Set-ADUser $user -Description "Disabled Per Request XXXX"
    Move-ADObject $user -TargetPath $TargetOU
}
```